# show this inequality $\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a(b+c)}(b^2+c^2-a^2-bc)\ge 0$

Tags: inequality, summation, sum-of-squares-method

let $a,b,c>0$,show this inequality
$$\sqrt{a(b+c)}(b^2+c^2-a^2-bc)+\sqrt{b(c+a)}(c^2+a^2-b^2-ca)+\sqrt{c(a+b)}(a^2+b^2-c^2-ab)\ge 0$$

I want use  S-O-S methods to solve ,But I can't, see this methods:https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h80127

so My inequality How to do?Thanks

Comment: It's the known Jiu Baoqian's conjecture. There is a smooth proof.

Answer (score 1):

*SOS method works*:

*Remarks*: I update my proof. My proof works for $a, b, c > 0$.

We need to prove that
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}
2\sqrt{a(b + c)}(b^2 + c^2 - a^2 - bc) \ge 0$$
or
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \sqrt{a(b + c)}\,\left[2c(c - a) - 2b(a - b) - (a - b)^2 + (b - c)^2 - (c - a)^2\right] \ge 0$$
or
\begin{align*}
 &\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \left[\left(2a\sqrt{b(c + a)} - 2b\sqrt{a(b + c)}\right) (a - b) \right. \\
 &\quad + \left. \left(-\sqrt{a(b + c)}- \sqrt{b(c + a)} + \sqrt{c(a + b)}\right)(a - b)^2\right]\ge 0
\end{align*}
or
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \left[-(a^2 - b^2)\sqrt{a(b + c)} + (a^2 - b^2)\sqrt{b(c + a)} + (a - b)^2\sqrt{c(a + b)}\right] \ge 0$$
or
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \left[-(a^2 - b^2)\frac{(a - b)c}{\sqrt{a(b + c)} + \sqrt{b(c + a)}} + (a - b)^2\sqrt{c(a + b)}\right] \ge 0$$
or
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \left[1 - \frac{\sqrt{c(a + b)}}{\sqrt{a(b + c)} + \sqrt{b(c + a)}}\right]\sqrt{c(a + b)}\,(a - b)^2 \ge 0$$
or
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{2ab\sqrt{c(a +b)} + 2\sqrt{abc(a + b)(b + c)(c + a)}}{[\sqrt{a(b + c)} + \sqrt{b(c + a)}]\,[\sqrt{a(b + c)} + \sqrt{b(c + a)} + \sqrt{c(a + b)}]}\,(a - b)^2 \ge 0$$
which is clearly true.

We are done.

Comment: Can you explain, how you got $S(a,b,c)$? The equality in the starting inequality occurs also for $abc=0$.        I don't see it from the expression of $S(a,b,c).$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thanks. I will check it.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I check it and it is no problem for $a, b, c > 0$. I add remarks to explain what happens if $abc = 0$.

Comment: I meant that for $c=0$ we have $\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{a(b+c)}(b^2+c^2-a^2-bc)=\sqrt{ab}(b^2-a^2)+\sqrt{ab}(a^2-b^2)=0.$ But $S(a,b,0)\neq0.$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Please check $S(a, b, 0) = 0$. $S(a, b, c) = \sqrt{c(a + b)}\left(1 - \frac{(a + b + c)\sqrt{abc(a + b)}}{[a\sqrt{b(c + a)} + b\sqrt{a(b + c)}]\,[\sqrt{(b + c)(c + a)} + \sqrt{ab}]}\right)$.  If $c = 0$, then $\sqrt{c(a + b)} = 0$, so $S(a,b, 0) = 0$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I update my proof.

Comment: The last step is not necessary already. Very nice solution!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thanks for comment which makes me improve my proof.